# How to order nodes in NEO4j which has other relationship too

Tags: neo4j

I have two nodes User and resources. Relations between them are:

```
User -> :HAS -> Resources
User -> :favourite -> Resources
```

I want to get resources that user has and also **order that resources which are also favourite**. In short I want to put favourite resources on top of all other resources that user has. How can i do it?

Comment: Do you mean that for user `Peter` you want to list all the `:RESOURCE` that he has, and on top you want to list the ones that are his `:FAVOURITE`? That is, you want only to return the one user's resources in order of his favour, as opposed to return one user's resources in order of another user's favour?

Comment: I want to get all resources that peter has. But i want to show/get resources that are favourite on top.

Comment: So far i have figured out that i need to use order by on all resources i got for user. But i am stuck at how to do order by on as has relationship or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can match on both types and then order by the count. So, users who have both `HAS` and `FAVOURITE` relationships with a resource will have a count of 2 on that resource and a count of 1 on resources that they only have a `HAS` relationship with.

```
MATCH (user:User)-[rel:HAS|FAVOURITE]->(resource:Resource)
WHERE user.name = "some user"
WITH user, resource, COUNT(rel) AS rels
ORDER BY rels DESC
RETURN user.name, resource.name;
```

This depends on redundancy in your model. I'm assuming that in order for a user to favorite a resource, they must "have" it too.

Answer (score 0):

Nicole already gave a good answer (+1), but if you have cases where

- a user doesn't have a resource but that resource is still a favourite
- a user has a resource twice, but it is not a favourite

you can handle these also if you are explicit about matching on `[:HAS]` and counting on `[:FAVOURITE]`

```
MATCH (user:User { name:"Peter" })-[:HAS]->(resource)
RETURN user.name, resource.name, LENGTH(user-[:FAVOURITE]->resource) AS favFactor
ORDER BY favFactor DESC
```

If a user has a resource twice it will be returned twice, but it will not be considered a favourite in virtue of having two matched relationships. Favourites that the user doesn't have won't be matched at all.